# No graph output from pycharm to jupyter notebook

Tags: python, json, dictionary, jupyter-notebook, geopandas

UPDATE:

It seems that I solved some issues (error code), but I can't see map.
Code running with no issue, but witouth output, why?

I'm using pycharm on anaconda environment.

Full code:

```
import geopandas as gpd

#Read shapefile using Geopandas
gdf = (gpd.read_file(r"C:\Users\gpont\PycharmProjects\pythonProject2\data\Map\map1\ne_110m_admin_0_countries.shp"))[['ADMIN', 'ADM0_A3', 'geometry']]

#Rename columns.
gdf.columns = ['country', 'country_code', 'geometry']
gdf.head()

print(gdf.head())

print(gdf[gdf['country'] == 'Antarctica'])
#Drop row corresponding to 'Antarctica'
gdf = gdf.drop(gdf.index[159])

import pandas as pd
datafile = 'data\Map\databaseCDP0.csv'

#Read csv file using pandas
df = pd.read_csv(datafile, skiprows = 1)
df.head()
print (df.head())

import json

#Read data to json.
df_json = json.loads(df.to_json())

#Convert to String like object.
json_data = json.dumps(df_json)

from bokeh.io import output_notebook, show, output_file
from bokeh.plotting import figure
from bokeh.models import GeoJSONDataSource, LinearColorMapper, ColorBar
from bokeh.palettes import brewer

#Input GeoJSON source that contains features for plotting.
geosource = GeoJSONDataSource(geojson = json_data)
#Define a sequential multi-hue color palette.
palette = brewer['YlGnBu'][8]
#Reverse color order so that dark blue is highest obesity.
palette = palette[::-1]
#Instantiate LinearColorMapper that linearly maps numbers in a range, into a sequence of colors.
color_mapper = LinearColorMapper(palette = palette, low = 0, high = 40)
#Define custom tick labels for color bar.
tick_labels = {'0': '0%', '5': '5%', '10':'10%', '15':'15%', '20':'20%', '25':'25%', '30':'30%','35':'35%', '40': '>40%'}
#Create color bar.
color_bar = ColorBar(color_mapper=color_mapper, label_standoff=8,width = 500, height = 20,
border_line_color=None,location = (0,0), orientation = 'horizontal', major_label_overrides = tick_labels)
#Create figure object.
p = figure(title = 'CDP_test', plot_height = 600 , plot_width = 950, toolbar_location = None)
p.xgrid.grid_line_color = None
p.ygrid.grid_line_color = None
#Add patch renderer to figure.
p.patches('xs','ys', source = geosource,fill_color = {'field' :'median_rating', 'transform' : color_mapper},
          line_color = 'black', line_width = 0.25, fill_alpha = 1)
#Specify figure layout.
p.add_layout(color_bar, 'below')
#Display figure inline in Jupyter Notebook.
output_notebook()
#Display figure.
show(p)
```

How can I show map on jupyter? I tried to run code on jupyter notebook (never used), but I receive error on library code (don't know why)

Comment: Have you tried installing Ipython in your anaconda environment? either using the GUI interface or a command prompt and conda install ipython

Comment: ```(base) C:\Users\gpont>conda install Ipython
Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): done
Solving environment: done

# All requested packages already installed. ```

Comment: Moreover, I installed ipython on pycharm, but dont't read json